# how to convert json data to csv and also keep the exact format in the excel

Tags: node.js, json, excel, csv, npm

I am using [objects-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objects-to-csv)  npm package to convert json data to csv in my node js on downloading the excel some dates are coming in exact format some dates are coming in different format  [image]

as shown in the picture if excel is able to differentiate between month and date exact format is coming or else different format is coming

is there any other npm package so when we convert to csv we will be able to save the format also

Comment: Are you sure that the two date formats are not just formatted in different ways ? Normally Excel would show if something is a string. If it's a date, you can format all the same way and still get a date.

Comment: I am sending the date as a string but still excel is changing the format

Comment: CSV is not an excel file, it's a text file. Open in a text editor and inspect the data there. Excel does all kinds of wierd things to it